# Regex: Exclude 5 digit numbers

Tags: regex

The regex should match every value (+ whitepsaces) that does not include a 5 digit number:

- 12345 - no match
- abc12345 - no match
- abc123456 - **match**
- 12345abc - no match
- 123456abc - **match**
- abc12345abc - no match
- abc123456abc - **match**
- abc123 - **match**

The current regex does not work properly as it does not exclude numbers with more than 5 digits

```
^(?!(?:\.|^)(\d{5})(?:\.|$)).*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/CRcZzM/1

Comment: Use `^(?!.*(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)).*` / `^(?!.*(?:\D|^)\d{5}(?!\d)).*`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wiq2P1/1). Or, in code, something like `if REGEXP.TEST(/(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)/, string) THEN return false`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Did it really work then? Please check the answer below, and let know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

You  may use

```
^(?!.*(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)).*
^(?!.*(?:\D|^)\d{5}(?!\d)).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wiq2P1/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is

  - `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.
  - `(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)` - a five digit string (`\d{5}`) neither preceded (`(?<!\d)`) nor followed with a digit (`(?!\d)`)
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

You do not need the last `.*` if you do not need a full string match.